# How to run g95 executable files in Mac OS X terminal

Tags: macos

I am completely new to this game, so please be gentle ;-)

I made an example program in Fortran 90, let's call it 'program.f90'.
I compile it:

```
g95 program.f90
```

It creates an executable called `a.out`.

How do I run this? It is supposed to print something to the screen, and get input from me, but I cannot figure out how to!

Comment: Re-tagged, as this is really a question about how to run a program on a Mac command line and not specific to FORTRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same terminal as you ran g95, type ./a.out - this should then read input from your terminal and write output to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
% ./a.out
```